# PouchDB with jquery mobile & phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, pouchdb

I'm trying to use the above three together in a mobile (android) app.
When I run it in firefox (20), Ubuntu (12.04), it works pretty goood, but when I load it into the phone (or the android emulator) it doesn't seem to be able to store the data.
When running in firefox the data gets stored inside the user profile directories in an sqlite db, but with an app? How to I tell PouchDB where to store the database? And how would I do it?

--Additional information

I've been doing some more testing with the PouchDB adapter types - in firefox and chrome.
WebSQL is not supported in firefox hence the use of chrome to test that.
Here are the scripts I'm loading in index.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="testa.js"></script>
```

Here is some of the relevant code which generates these logs

```
console.log("Creating the database" + JSON.stringify(userdata));
Pouch('idb://'+userdata.username, function(err, database){
    if (err) {
    console.log('Failed to create database:'+ JSON.stringify(err));
        return {'ok': false, 'reason':'Failed to create database:'+ userdata.username};
    } else {
        pdb = database;
        console.log('Created database:'+ JSON.stringify(userdata.username));
        Pouch('idb://cred', function(err, credb){
           if (err) {
               console.log('Failed to create database: cred'+ JSON.stringify(err));
               //
               return {'ok': false, 'reason':'Failed to create database: cred'};
           } else {
               pdbcred = credb;
               console.log('Created database: cred');
               ...
```

In firefox, the output of the console log is as follows, with idb adaptor - Pouch("idb://idbx")

```
testa.js (line 296)     Creating the database{"username":"idbx","email":"idbx@asdf.asdf","password":"password"} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 759) idb://idbx 
pouchd...htly.js (line 764) ["idb://idbx","idb","idbx"] 
pouchd...htly.js (line 767) idb 
pouchd...htly.js (line 768) {} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 772) {"name":"idbx","adapter":"idb"} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 759) idb://_pouch__allDbs 
pouchd...htly.js (line 764) ["idb://_pouch__allDbs","idb","_pouch__allDbs"] 
pouchd...htly.js (line 767) idb 
pouchd...htly.js (line 768) {} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 772) {"name":"_pouch__allDbs","adapter":"idb"} 
testa.js (line 303)     Created database:"idbx" 
pouchd...htly.js (line 759) idb://cred 
pouchd...htly.js (line 764) ["idb://cred","idb","cred"] 
pouchd...htly.js (line 767) idb 
pouchd...htly.js (line 768) {} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 772) {"name":"cred","adapter":"idb"} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 759) idb://_pouch__allDbs 
pouchd...htly.js (line 764) ["idb://_pouch__allDbs","idb","_pouch__allDbs"] 
pouchd...htly.js (line 767) idb 
pouchd...htly.js (line 768) {} 
pouchd...htly.js (line 772) {"name":"_pouch__allDbs","adapter":"idb"} 
testa.js (line 311)     Created database: cred 
testa.js (line 328)     Saved document:{"_id":"idbx","password":"password","email":"idbx@asdf.asdf","savecred":true}:{"ok":true,"id":"idbx","rev":"1-2f0ff07a7c0d8fb6f172a6bfe8a9174f"}
```

Changed the adaptor to websql and tested on chrome - works fine.

Loaded the websql version apk into the emulator (using google APIs rather than the 4.2.2 apis) and this is what comes up on logcat (with idb the logcat is identical):

```
04-19 00:28:26.571: I/Web Console(22733): Creating the database{"username":"websqlo","email":"websqlo@asdf.asdf","password":"password"} at file:///android_asset/www/testa.js:296
04-19 00:28:26.601: I/Web Console(22733): websql://websqlo at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js:759
04-19 00:28:26.611: I/Web Console(22733): ["websql://websqlo","websql","websqlo"] at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js:764
04-19 00:28:26.631: I/Web Console(22733): "websql" at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js:767
04-19 00:28:26.651: I/Web Console(22733): {} at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js:768
04-19 00:28:26.751: E/Web Console(22733): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'valid' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/jquery.mobile/pouch-20130419/pouchdb-nightly.js:769
```

The entries from pouchdb-nightly were from some console.log statements I added into the pouch js file.
The actual code around the js is as follows (had to stringify because logcat won't show anything but plain text):

```
Pouch.parseAdapter = function(name) {
  console.log(name);
  var match = name.match(/([a-z\-]*):\/\/(.*)/);
  var adapter;
  if (match) {
    // the http adapter expects the fully qualified name
    console.log(JSON.stringify(match));
    name = /http(s?)/.test(match[1]) ? match[1] + '://' + match[2] : match[2];
    adapter = match[1];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(adapter));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Pouch.adapters))
    if (!Pouch.adapters[adapter].valid()) {
      throw 'Invalid adapter';
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify({name: name, adapter: match[1]}));
    return {name: name, adapter: match[1]};
  }
```

Would appreciate any help/suggestions on a way to solve this..thanks to chesles and frequent for your suggestions - I will go and look at them now.
FYI - a url like Pouch("idb://testpath/testdb") doesn't work...complains about meta-data.
Somewhere in the back of my head I'm thinking that there should be a way to tell PouchDB where to store the file (especially in a app) and also things about read/write permissions on the directories. Perhaps I should be looking somewhere else...all help is welcome.

Comment: Can you post some code, or describe what you've tried? I haven't got an android dev environment set up, but you should be able to just say `var db = Pouch('db_name')` and start using the database. You might have a look at the ios starter-kit that jchris made, it should be somewhat similar to what you need to do for android: https://github.com/jchris/pouchdb-phonegap-ios

Comment: Maybe not helpful, but if you can't get it to work, you could also have a look at [jIO](http://www.j-io.org/), whose API is mapped to PouchDB/CouchDB. Also stores JSON, can sync across multiple storages (webDav, xWiki, S3, localstorage) and has it's own query module. I'm not using it with phonegap, but it works fine with JQM and Android.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the additional info. I will look through it in detail a bit later. Have you tried just using a database name, e.g. `"my_database"`, without any adapter prefix? Pouchdb will automatically detect the adapter it needs to use. When used in a browser there's no file, Pouchdb uses whatever local storage API is available (websql, indexeddb). As far as I understand it, with phonegap you're just dealing with an embedded browser, so it's still using a local storage APIs, not a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there's a few things to note here:

1. PouchDB will use the best adapter available for a platform if you simply give it a database name, with no `adapter://` prefix. If you want to use a local-storage adapter, this is probably the best way to create databases, since you can use the same code no matter what browser you are running on; as long as it supports WebSQL or IndexedDB it *should* just work.
2. There was an open issue tracking support for PhoneGap for android [here](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/issues/377), which was closed 4 days ago, confirmed to be working. Unfortunately I can't personally confirm this right now, but it *should* work.
3. Check out the notes from howonlee on pull request [670](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/pull/670), specifically about wrapping everything in a `deviceready` callback:

   > Note that we must create and use the db inside an onDeviceReady() function, because we use websql which only becomes available to us after the deviceready event.

Comment: Hi, you've provided lots of good information and things to follow up. I'm out of town ATM and will be back about Wendesday, when I will definitely follow up the links and report back on the outcome. I actually tried it originally without the adapter in front but it gave me pretty much the same result, so after going through the pouchDB API one more time I thought I'd see if it was a particular adapter causing the problem...I've looked at the links and they look very promising - will get back on Wendenesday.

Comment: Cool. I'm betting it's the `deviceready` thing then. Looking forward to hearing your results :)

Comment: Great - the deviceready callback seems to have solved the problem with the 'undefined' error in the logcat but there seems to be another problem in that the pouchDB callbacks (ONLY with chrome - firefox is fine) gets called multiple times indefinitely. I'm guessing I didn't see this before because of the 'undefined' error. Also the same problem when I loaded it into the emulator. But that's a different problem - this one can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. If you don't figure out that other issue, go ahead and post another question on here, or even better open an issue on github :)

Comment: Actually I figured it out - the real reason I didn't see this issue before was because I was using the adaptors when creating the DB in this post. The issue only arises with chrome when the adaptor is not explicit. It seems that in chrome, the adaptor is not optional. I've raised an issue in github - not a huge issue, but something that could save some people a bit of time.